# How to know path "gs://bucket1/folder_x" existing or not in GCP bucket

Tags: google-cloud-platform, bucket, gsutil

Is there a '''gsutil''' command can tell me if the  path '''gs://bucket1/folder1_x/folder2_y/''' existing or not? Is there a '''ping''' command in gsutil?
I use Jenkins parameters folder_x and folder_y which value input by user, and joined by pipeline. Currently, if the dir does exist, the pipeline will show success. But if the path is wrong, the pipeline will be interrupted and shows failure.

Tried use gsutil stat and gsutil -q stat, it can test '''gs://bucket1/folder1_x/folder2_y/file1''', but not for dir.

'''groovy

pipeline {

```
stages {

    stage('Check existing dirs') {

        steps {
            script{

                if (params['Action'] =="List_etl-output") {

                    def Output_Data="${params['Datasource']}".toString().split(",").collect{"\"" + it + "\""}
                    def Output_Stage="${params['Etl_Output_Stage']}".toString().split(",").collect{"\"" + it + "\""}
                    for (folder1 in Output_Data) {
                        for (folder2 in Output_Stage) {
                        sh(script:  """

                           gsutil ls -r gs://bucket1/*/$Data/$Stage
                          
                      """ )

                    }
                }
            }
        }
      }
    }
```

}
}

'''

I was use gsutil to check if the path gs://bucket1/*/$Data/$Stage available or not. The $Data and $Stage are given by user input,  the Jenkins pipeline interrupted when the path not available. I want gsutil can skip the wrong path when it's not available.

Comment: Just a note, there are no folders in google storage in the usual sense, it creates an illusion of hierarchy when in fact it uses a flat name space.

Comment: Here is more on that: [link](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/gsutil/addlhelp/HowSubdirectoriesWork). What you can do is you can try to list it and if you get an exception - no "folder", otherwise if the list is only the "folder" itself - it is "empty", else if the list has >=2 entries - it isn't "empty".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The directory doesn't exist in Cloud Storage. It's a graphical representation. All the blob are stored at to bucket root and their name is composed of the full path (with / that you interpret as directory, but not). It's also for this that you can only search on prefix.

To answer your question, you can use this latest feature: search on the prefix. If there is 1 element, the folder exist BECAUSE there is at least 1 blob with this prefix. Here an example in Python (I don't know your language, I can adapt it in several language if you need)

```
    from google.cloud import storage
    client = storage.Client()
    bucket = client.get_bucket('bucket1')
    if len(list(bucket.list_blobs(prefix='folder_x/'))):
      print('there is a file in the "directory"')
    else:
      print('No file with this path, so no "directory"')
```

---

Here the example in Groovy

```
import com.google.cloud.storage.Bucket
import com.google.cloud.storage.Storage
import com.google.cloud.storage.StorageOptions

Storage storage = StorageOptions.getDefaultInstance().service
Bucket bucket = storage.get("bucket1")

System.out.println(bucket.list(Storage.BlobListOption.prefix("folder_x/")).iterateAll().size())
```

Comment: is len() needed here really?

Comment: Could it be `if any(bucket.list_blobs(prefix='folder_x/')):`?

Comment: As a heads up there are commercial tools that create 0 length objects to represent directories. Object metadata is used to record timestamp, permissions, object type, etc.

Comment: @JohnHanley, not especially commercial tools. Even the GCS cloud console allows to "create directory" with empty content and empty name. That brings more and more confusion on the real behavior of GCS and users are less and less aware of the current strengths and weaknesses of the GCS platform, use it not correctly and ask questions here!!

Comment: @guillaume blaquiere. I'm using Jenkinsfile, groovy language. Could you please help to adapt it to groovy? Thanks

Comment: @markzhu - Create a new question. Google has examples in Kotlin, converting to Groovy  should be very easy. https://cloud.google.com/kotlin

Comment: Thanks @guillaume blaquiere. You are genius.